# Cert/client authentication with Nginx with multiple clients using different certs

Tags: nginx, client-certificates

I'm working on a small Flask based service behind Nginx that serves some content over HTTP.  It will do so using two-way certificate authentication - which I understand how to do with Nginx - but users must log in and load their own certificate that will be used for the auth piece.

So the scenario is:

- User has a server that generates a cert that is used for client authentication.
- They log into the service to upload that cert for their server.
- Systems that pull the cert from the user's server can now reach an endpoint on my service that serves the content and authenticates using the cert.

I can't find anything in the Nginx docs that says I can have a single keystore or directory that Nginx looks at to match the cert for an incoming request. I know I can configure this 'per-server' in Nginx.

The idea I currently have is that I allow the web app to trigger a script that reads the Nginx conf file, inserts a new server entry and a specified port with the path to the uploaded cert and the sends the HUP signal to reload Nginx.

I'm wondering if anyone in the community has done something similar to this before with Nginx or if they have a better solution for the odd scenario I'm presenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot more research and reading some of the documentation on nginx.com I found that I was way over complicating this.

Instead of modifying my configuration in `sites-available` I should be adding and removing config files from `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` and then telling Nginx to reload by calling `sudo nginx -s reload`.

I'll have the app call a script to run the needed commands and add the script into the sudoers file for the `www-data` user.